# How to fake on demand storage disk in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

Part of my code creates an [on-demand storage disk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#on-demand-disks) using config values that are stored in the database. I am writing a feature test for this code, how do I get my test to use fake storage when this disk is created instead of trying to actually create the real connection? With any named storage disks I just do `Storage::fake('mydisk')` at the start of my test but since it is on-demand it doesn't have a name.

Comment: Create fake name with faker and pass it to tested code. Than fake disk with this fake name

Comment: Where are you instantiating this on demand storage?  I'm trying to determine where in the lifecycle to pull the info out of the db and create these storage disks for the rest of the app to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to crack it in the end:

```
$localDisk = Storage::fake('local');

Storage::shouldReceive('build')->with([
    'driver' => 'sftp',
    'host' => $endpoint->host,
    'username' => $endpoint->username,
    'password' => $endpoint->password,
    'port' => $endpoint->port ?? 22,
])->andReturn($localDisk);
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve my issue as well!